# Button borders in a grouped static UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uibutton

I have placed a UIButton inside a static grouped cell and tried to make it fit to the cell border, but get this kind of double-lines:

[image]

I tried changing the separator style, but it didn't help. Is there a way to make the border-lines of the button invisible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just make a label on the cell and then use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` instead of putting a button inside the cell?

Comment: If I got it right didSelectRowAtIndexPath: should not be implemented on static tables. And: the feeling of pressing a button is different than pressing a label, or is it possible to get that short "selected-state" feeling from a label in a tablerow?

Comment: gschandler's answer bellow is a much better way to do it.  Otherwise, just change the button type to "Custom" and it gets rid of the rounded rectangle around it.

Comment: Thanks, that was the missing piece of information!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change button type to custom and it will get rid of the Round Rectangle around the button.

Answer (score 3):

From a design perspective, it might be better to add the button as a footer view for the table instead of embedded in a cell. Take a look at Calendar app on the iPhone. When you edit an existing event, they add a button at the bottom of the table for deleting the event. Theirs is a bit fancier than a simple rounded rect button, but that's trivial to do as well.

Embed your login button in a generic `UIView` and add it as such:

```
UIView *footerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:...];
UIButton *logInButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
// do button set up here, including sizing and centering, and add to footer view
[footerView addSubview:logInButton];

self.tableView.tableFooterView = footerView;
[footerView release];
```

Comment: unfortunately I have another section below the login section - sorry for not posting this. the solution looks very elegant. I guess this also work for viewForFooterInSection